# How to determine the version of a library

Tags: python, shared-libraries

How to determine the version of a python library, from a python piece of code, when the library has no **version** attribute?

Here is the example of the Pyvisa library which  had no **version** attribute initially. I have done the following code that returns unknown for the version when I can't determine it.

```
try:
    import visa
    from visa import VisaIOError, Error
    pyvisa_version=0.
    try:
        pyvisa_version=float(visa.__version__)
    except:
        pass
    if pyvisa_version >0.:
        print 'pyvisa version: %f ' % pyvisa_version
    else:
        print 'pyvisa version: unknown'
    if pyvisa_version <= 1.5:
        try:
            from visa import vpp43
        except:
            print 'Cannot import vpp43.'
except:
    print 'Cannot import visa'
```

Does anyone has a better solution  when there is no **version** attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This will get you the versions of every library on your system.

```
pip freeze
```

or for python 3

```
pip3 freeze
```

It will output a list to the terminal you've run it in.

Following the comment below:

```
import os
import glob
d = os.path.dirname('libname'.__file__)
dirs = glob.glob(d+'*')
for d in dirs:
if d.endswith('.dist-info'):
    d = d.split('/')
    f=d[-1]
    f = f.split('-')
    f = f[1:]
    f = ''.join(f)
```

and 'f[:-9]' now contains the version number.

Comment: I am not sure I was clear. I want to determine the version from a piece of python code running on a machine I don't know. Is it safe to rely on pip being installed? Should not I anticipate my code being used on a machine with python and pyVisa, but without pip  being installed?

Comment: OK do you know what operating system it has?

Answer (score 1):

you could try the pkg_resources package?

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution('visa').version
```

result - '1.0.0'

from what I've read previously, this method works when there is no **version** attribute and does not rely on pip either.

but this also depends on having this package installed..

EDIT

this specific package has a visa.version module which is just a .py file with the version in it..

file_loc = visa.version

then you could parse the version out of it? probably an easier way.. but an idea