# How to check the version of intel MKL pardiso in python?

Tags: python, pardiso

I know that I can get the version of pardiso if I import MKL directly to python like this:

```
import mkl
mkl.get_version_string()
```

But if I am using the following code to import intel MKL pardiso:

```
import sys
import ctypes

def get_libmkl():
    # linux system
    return ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
```

And I use the following to initialize pardiso solver:

```
libmkl = get_libmkl()
mkl_pardiso = libmkl.pardiso
```

In this case, how could I know which version of pardiso that I am using?

Comment: Have you tried `pkg_resources`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917569/how-to-determine-the-version-of-a-library) question may help.